# Login into web site using Python

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

This question has been addresses in various shapes and flavors but I have not been able to apply any of the solutions I read online.

I would like to use Python to log into the site: https://app.ninchanese.com/login
and then reach the page: https://app.ninchanese.com/leaderboard/global/1

I have tried various stuff but without success...
Using POST method:

```
import urllib
import requests
oURL = 'https://app.ninchanese.com/login'
oCredentials = dict(email='myemail@hotmail.com', password='mypassword')
oSession = requests.session()
oResponse = oSession.post(oURL, data=oCredentials)
oResponse2 = oSession.get('https://app.ninchanese.com/leaderboard/global/1')
```

Using the authentication function from requests package

```
import requests
oSession = requests.session()
oResponse = oSession.get('https://app.ninchanese.com/login', auth=('myemail@hotmail.com', 'mypassword'))
oResponse2 = oSession.get('https://app.ninchanese.com/leaderboard/global/1')
```

Whenever I print oResponse2, I can see that I'm always on the login page so I am guessing the authentication did not work.

Could you please advise how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the `csrf_token` along with your login request:

```
import urllib
import requests
import bs4

URL = 'https://app.ninchanese.com/login'
credentials = dict(email='myemail@hotmail.com', password='mypassword')
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(URL)
html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
credentials['csrf_token'] = html.find('input', {'name':'csrf_token'})['value']
response = session.post(URL, data=credentials)
response2 = session.get('https://app.ninchanese.com/leaderboard/global/1')
```

Comment: Hello Daniel and thanks a lot for taking the time to anwser!
I have tried what you described above but when I print(response2.text) I have the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\alexis.rolland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 5722-5724: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Ok great! your solution actually worked and I was able to print by adding .encode("utf-8")... which gives me this: print(response2.text.encode("utf-8"))