# Parsing data from Canon i-sensys printer with python

Tags: python

I'm new with python and I would like to parse the data from the printer log.
I wrote some code based on this [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571798/login-into-web-site-using-python/40571864#40571864)
but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import data
login_url = "http://192.168.178.100"
PrintData_url = 'http://192.168.178.100/jhis_plist.html'

payload = {"Abteilungs-ID": "7654321", "PIN": "7654321"}


r = requests.post(login_url, payload)

with requests.Session() as session:
    page = session.get(login_url)
    html=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    csrf_token = html.find('input', {'name':'csrf_token'})['value']
    data_to_login = {'Abteilungs-ID':data.Abteilungs-ID, 'PIN':data.password, 'csrf_token':csrf_token}
    r=session.post('192.168.178.100', data_to_login)
    print(r.text)
```

Error code:
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
File "/media//Drucker_login.py", line 17, in 
csrf_token = html.find('input', {'name': 'CSRFToken'})['value']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Looks like the `html.find('input', {'name':'csrf_token'})` isn't returning a dictionary like the code expects. It would be helpful to share the html you get from beautiful soup to understand why you aren't finding that element